# Can not get my BIND server to work

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to setup a BIND server. I have read some tutorials on the internet, but I have still not got it to work. The OS of the machine that is runnig the BIND daemon is CentOS 6.4 with IP address 192.168.1.13.

In `/etc/named.conf` I have added these lines:

```
zone "mydomain.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "mydomain.com.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "mydomain.com.rev";
};
```

In `/var/named/mydomain.com.zone` I have this:

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL 3D

@       SOA     ns.mydomain.com.     root.mydomain.com. (12 4h 1h 1w 1h)

@       IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.

ns.mydomain.com.     IN      A       192.168.1.13

www                  IN      A       192.168.1.13
```

In `/var/named/mydomain.com.rev` I have this:

```
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

$TTL 3D

@       SOA     ns.mydomain.com.     root.mydomain.com. (12 4h 1h 1w 1h)

@       IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.

211     IN      PTR     ns.mydomain.com
```

On my **other** machine I have configured `/etc/resolv.conf` to contain these lines:

```
domain mydomain.com
search mydomain.com
nameserver 192.168.1.13
```

When I run `nslookup www.mydomain.com` I just get

```
Server:   192.168.1.13
Address:  192.168.1.13#53

**server can`t find www.mydomain.com.mydomain.com: REFUSED
```

I have checked with netstat that BIND is listening for all connections, IPTables is not blocking incomming connections and port 53 is open on the BIND server when I run nmap from my other computer.

And, of course, BIND is running.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Post the complete `/etc/named.conf` also check the logfile of BIND if it logged any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that your bind configuration is okay:

```
# named-checkconf
# named-checkzone mydomain.com /var/named/mydomain.com.zone
```

After that check that you are able to resolve correctly your zone

```
# dig mydomain.com SOA @localhost
```

But according to your configuration, it should work fine from the machine which have bind installed on it.

Are you using views? Is this zone in a view? If you are using views you have to make sure that the client trying to resolve from this view is in "match-clients {}"

Next check the following 2 parameters in named.conf:

```
listen-on port 53 { 192.168.1.13; };
allow-query { any; };
```

You will have to restart bind after editing.

Comment: `named-checkconf`gives no output. `named-checkzone` says mydomain.com configuration is OK. When I run `nslookup www.mydomain.com` from the BIND machine it seems to work (after editing /etc/resolv.conf). But it still does not work from my client machine. I don´t know what views are. I am totally new to BIND and this is my first step to learn it. I made a fresh install and just edited named.conf and created the other two files (mydomain.com.zone and mydomain.com.rev) so I suppose I do not use any views.

Comment: If named-checkconf doesn't give output, then it executed without problems.

Comment: Ok, check the following 2 parameters in named.conf:

listen-on port 53 { 192.168.1.13 };
allow-query { any; };

You will have to restart bind after editing.

Comment: `allow-query { any; };` made it! It was first set to `localhost`. Thank you!